# Failure on calling a method from JUnit Test Case

Tags: java, junit

I have a question:

I have such a method in my JUnit Test case:

```
@Test
public void test1st_scenario() {

    out = Mockito.mock(PrintStream.class);
    System.setOut(out);
    restaurant = new Restaurant();
    employee = new Employee(null, null, null);

    ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employees.add(new Employee("Luciano", "chef", ExperienceLevel.LOW));
    employees.add(new Employee("Naved", "waiter", ExperienceLevel.LOW));
    employees.add(new Employee("Fabrizio", "waiter", ExperienceLevel.LOW));
    employees.add(new Employee("Amnir", "waiter", ExperienceLevel.LOW));
    employees.add(new Employee("Abel", "barman", ExperienceLevel.LOW));

    restaurant.setBudget(10000);
    employee.increaseExperience(employees, 1, "Luciano");
    Mockito.verify(out).println("The chef experience level increased");
    Assert.assertEquals(8800, restaurant.getBudget());
}
```

And increaseExperience method in Employee class is:

```
public void increaseExperience(ArrayList<Employee> employees,
        int numberOfEmployee, String employeeName) {
    restaurant = new Restaurant();
    String[] parts = employeeName.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEmployee; i++) 
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < employees.size(); a++) 
        {
            if (employees.get(a).name.equals(parts[i])) 
            {
                if (employees.get(a).job.equals("chef") || employees.get(a).job.equals("barman")) 
                {
                    if (employees.get(a).experience.equals(ExperienceLevel.LOW) || employees.get(a).experience.equals(ExperienceLevel.MEDIUM)) 
                    {
                        if (restaurant.getBudget() >= 1200) 
                        {
                            restaurant.setBudget(restaurant.getBudget() - 1200);
                            if (i == 0)
                                System.out.println("The " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is increased");
                            else
                                System.out.println(" and the " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is increased");
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            if (i == 0)
                                System.out.println("The " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is failed to increase");
                            else
                                System.out.println(" and the " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is failed to increase");
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (employees.get(a).experience.equals(ExperienceLevel.HIGH)) 
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                            System.out.println("The " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is increased");
                        else
                            System.out.println(" and the " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is increased");
                    }
                } 
                else if (employees.get(a).job.equals("waiter")) 
                {
                    if (employees.get(a).experience.equals(ExperienceLevel.LOW) || employees.get(a).experience.equals(ExperienceLevel.MEDIUM)) 
                    {
                        if (restaurant.getBudget() >= 800) 
                        {
                            restaurant.setBudget(restaurant.getBudget() - 800);
                            if (i == 0)
                                System.out.println("The " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is increased");
                            else
                                System.out.println(" and the " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is increased");
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            if (i == 0)
                                System.out.println("The " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is failed to increase");
                            else
                                System.out.println(" and the " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is failed to increase");
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (employees.get(a).experience.equals(ExperienceLevel.HIGH)) 
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                            System.out.println("The " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is increased");
                        else
                            System.out.println(" and the " + employees.get(a).job + " experience level is increased");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I set the budget as 10000 in my JUnit Test method, I cannot I have to get it as 8800 back. But still I get 10000. Probably there is a failure in calling increaseExperience method.

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems more likely that it's a bug in the code you're calling. I suggest you stop mocking `System.out` - then you'll get your debug logging... Additionally, you should step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: I think you should get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException?

Comment: But Jon, when I ignore mocking, I still cannot get 8800. It doesn't reduce anything.

Comment: No Almas, when I use Mockito, arguments are being different. When I ignore mocking, I don't get 8800

Comment: @yeniden: "It doesn't reduce anything" - it gives you debugging information! What's the point of having all those `System.out.println` lines if you then turn them off in tests, even when you don't understand what's going on? It doesn't solve the problem *in itself* but it helps you find the problem.

Comment: Because I have to test all the printlns in other scenraios. That's why I put many printlns there.

Comment: But you aren't interested in what they're saying when your program isn't behaving as you expect it to? Do you not understand that it will help you see what's going wrong? (As would debugging, which it's not clear you've tried...)

Comment: So right now, which kind of implementation I can do? Could you write me an example?

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem, right at the start of your `increaseExperience` method:

```
restaurant = new Restaurant();
```

The restaurant you're working with in the method is entirely separate from the restaurant in the test.

Perhaps you should be passing in the restaurant as another parameter? Or possibly the employee should know the restaurant they're working for?

(It's also not at all clear why you're calling `increaseExperience` on an `Employee` with no useful information - it sounds like either it should be an instance method on `Employee` *without* you passing in the employees, or it should be an instance method on `Restaurant`, at which point you should remove the `restuarant` variable, or it should be a *static* method on `Employee` as it acts on many employees, not just one... Fundamentally, I think you need to revisit your design.)

Comment: Actually only thing I want to do is increase the level of experience of an employee in the restaurant. So I have to check the budget at first in the restaurant, so in this way I can increase thelevel or not. if I don't call restaurant, I cannot get the budget.

Comment: @yeniden: You've missed my point entirely, I think. You're creating a *new* restaurant at the start of the method. Assuming each `Restaurant` has a separate budget, how do you expect the restaurant you create at the start of the method to have anything to do with the restaurant you're creating in your test? (As I said in my answer, I'd also strongly encourage you to revisit your design...)

Comment: Jon, right now I've created new Restaurant() instance at outside of the method. But still I get the same error.

Comment: @yeniden: That still doesn't sound like the instance in `Employee` has anything to do with the instance you're creating in your test. I'm afraid I don't have time to help you further - I've explained what's wrong, given an option to fix it, explained design flaws, and given you hints for two different ways of improving your diagnostics (logging and debugging)... I'm afraid you'll have to do the rest yourself.